# CentOSとWindows間での共有フォルダを介したファイル移動を高速化するには？

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

windowsの共有フォルダをcentosにマウントし、そのデータをmvコマンドでcentos上に退避しています。

しかし、この時の速度がかなり遅く時間がかかってしまいます。
100MBで3~6分程度

なんとか高速かする方法は無いでしょうか。

windowsのクライアント端末からsshでcentosへ接続し、mvコマンドを実行しています。

また、初歩的なことで申し訳ないのですが、sshで接続しているウィンドウを閉じてもmvコマンドの実行は継続されますか？

Comment: データの移動に当たって、別の方法("WindowsからLinux領域をマウント"やFTP,SCPを使用etc..)は選択肢としてアリでしょうか？

Comment: 高速化するには遅い原因を絞り込まなければ行けないと思います。使っているネットワークの速度、Windows、Centosそれぞれの負荷状況、など分かれば質問を編集して追記してもらえますか？そういった情報がヒントになり詳しい人からの回答がつくかもしれません。

Comment: 別の方法を取りたいのですが、運用の関係上、別の転送の方法は取れません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！それぞれのネットワーク速度、負荷状況を調べてみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mv` といってもこの場合、ネットワークを経由した異マシン間でのコピーですから「遅い」と感じるのは仕方ないところでは？で、どうすれば高速化するかですが、やはり測定から。遅くないところをいくらいじっても実所要時間は変化しません。

Windows 側ならタスクマネージャを起動してから `mv` を開始し、一番負担のかかっているのがネットワークなのかCPUなのかディスク装置なのかを見てみましょう。

参考：ウチの LAN で、同一スイッチング HUB に接続されている 100BASE-T マシン同士での `ftp` で 86MiB の転送に 7.33sec = 11.73MiB/sec このときネットワーク使用率がほぼ 100% で CPU 使用率は 10% 程度でした。

ログアウトしても処理を継続したいなら `nohup` コマンドが使えます。

```
$ nohup mv sourcefile targetdir &
$ ctrl-D でログアウトしても処理継続
```

エラー発生時などに操作員の介入が必要なコマンドに対して `nohup` 使うといろいろまずいので、そういうのには使わないでください。

Comment: はい、ありがとうございます。早速どこに負荷がかかっているかを確認してみます！nohupも早速実践します。